# docker environment variable not loaded in pytest and FastApi

Tags: python, docker, pytest, fastapi

This is a FastApi test docker environment with postgrade DB. paths are several and it need to test it.
As see in FastApi guide I tried to use `pytest` however enviroment variable in compose.yaml does not pass to path as they're working on main app.

error returned is because environment `ENVIRONMENT=dev` and `TESTING=0` seems not loaded. Does tests can be done loading docker enviroment

Test file is:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from app.main import app

client = TestClient(app)


def test_read_main():
    response = client.get("/ping")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"ping": "pong!", "environment": "dev", "testing": 0}
```

Error got it:

```
test_main.py F                                                                        [100%]

=========================== FAILURES ===========================
________________________ test_read_main ________________________

    def test_read_main():
        response = client.get("/ping")
        assert response.status_code == 200
>       assert response.json() == {"ping": "pong!", "environment": "dev", "testing": 0}
E       AssertionError: assert {'environment...esting': True} == {'environment... 'testing': 0}
E         Omitting 1 identical items, use -vv to show
E         Differing items:
E         {'testing': True} != {'testing': 0}
E         {'environment': 'dev2'} != {'environment': 'dev'}
E         Use -v to get more diff

test_main.py:11: AssertionError
=================== short test summary info ====================
FAILED test_main.py::test_read_main - AssertionError: assert {'environment...esting': True} == {'...
====================== 1 failed in 0.44s =======================
```

project files:

```
# services/backend/app/main.py

from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, HTTPException
from config import get_settings, Settings

app = FastAPI()

# app.include_router(admin.router)


@app.get("/ping")
def pong(settings: Settings = Depends(get_settings)):
    return {
        "ping": "pong!",
        "environment": settings.environment,
        "testing": settings.testing,
    }
```

```
# backend/config.py

import logging
from functools import lru_cache

from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings

log = logging.getLogger("uvicorn")


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    environment: str = "dev2"
    testing: bool = 1
    # DATABASE_URL: str
    # SECRET_KEY: str
    # ALGORITHM: str
   

@lru_cache
def get_settings() -> BaseSettings:
    log.info("Loading config settings from environment...")
    return Settings()
```

file estructure and docker components are

```
.
├── services
│   ├── backend
│   │    ├── alembic.ini
│   │    ├── app
│   │    │   ├── __init__.py
│   │    │   ├── main.py
│   │    │   ├── models.py
│   │    │   ├── routers
│   │    │   │     ├── admin.py
│   │    │   │     ├── admin_schemas.py
│   │    │   ├── schemas.py
│   │    ├── config.py
│   │    ├── db.py
│   │    ├── Dockerfile
│   │    ├── migrations
│   │    ├── requirements.txt
│   │    ├── setup.py
│   │    └── test_main.py
│   ├── compose.yaml
│   └── frontend
└── tree.txt
```

docker file

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.11
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-slim as base

# Prevents Python from writing pyc files.
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Keeps Python from buffering stdout and stderr to avoid situations where
# the application crashes without emitting any logs due to buffering.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the source code into the container.
COPY . .

# Expose the port that the application listens on.
EXPOSE 8004

# Run the application.
CMD uvicorn app.main:app --reload --workers 2 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
```

compose file

```
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 8004:8000
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=dev
      - TESTING=0
    networks:
      mynet:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.10
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypass123
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      mynet:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.23
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  admin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: testemail@gmail.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: mypass123
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - admin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    networks:
      mynet:

volumes:
  db-data:
  admin-data:
networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.5.0.0/24
          gateway: 10.5.0.1
```

Comment: Could you try `printenv` or `env` command inside a container? Otherwise, you can log it inside `get_settings` function.